# Touchpad Setting Switched each others

Tags: touchpad, bug-reporting

I have a problem. When I tap touchpad with 1 finger it doesn't work. But when I tap 2 fingers my touchpad it works only tap . And my 3 fingers settings working on scrolling.

1 finger --> Not working

2 fingers --> one click

3 finger --> only scrolling.

Comment: What is the OS? I don't have this problem.

Comment: This is ubuntu 20.04

Comment: How did this happen? You probably changed config files. There are 2 places where to look for them. But you should know what you did.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what i changed settings files . But I didn't touch they

Comment: Boot with a LiveUSB and check how the touchpad works.

Comment: yeap, We fixed it. I restart my laptop. and it works correctly. But I haven't known yet this error. So i haven't turned off my laptop since a few days . Probably so this. Thank You very much